# URL rewrite working for .html but not .php

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL rewrite that strips away the file extension. It's working with `.html` pages but it gives me a "404 Page Not Found" error with `.php` files.

Here is my full `.htaccess` file

```
# The following will allow you to use URLs such as the following:
#
#   example.com/anything
#   example.com/anything/
#
# Which will actually serve files such as the following:
#
#   example.com/anything.html
#   example.com/anything.php
#
# But *only if they exist*, otherwise it will report the usual 404 error.

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^inaflashgraphics.com$
rewriterule ^ "http\:\/\/www\.inaflashgraphics\.com\/" [R=301,L] #4e2f2fa615667

# Remove trailing slashes.
# e.g. example.com/foo/ will redirect to example.com/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=permanent,QSA]

# Redirect to HTML if it exists.
# e.g. example.com/foo will display the contents of example.com/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

# Redirect to PHP if it exists.
# e.g. example.com/foo will display the contents of example.com/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest adding a RewriteLog and setting the RewriteLogLevel to 5 so you can see step-by-step what it is doing.

Comment: After your "RewriteEngine On" add the following on separate lines: "RewriteLog /path/to/your/new/log" and "RewriteLogLevel 5". This will create a log file at the path you specify, and will write every single step that the Rewrite Engine makes when trying to determine the correct file to serve. Obviously, remember to remove this when you have resolved the problem!!

Comment: adding that made the whole website not work :(

Comment: Ah sorry - you can't use RewriteLog in a .htaccess file, my bad. You can put it in the vhost config or the httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out, this code works for me.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^inaflashgraphics.com$
rewriterule ^ "http\:\/\/www\.inaflashgraphics\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Redirect to HTML if it exists.
# e.g. example.com/foo will display the contents of example.com/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.inaflashgraphics\.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Try putting this before the html bit

Comment: try also removing the slashes.